# Micrium File system partition issue

Tags: file, system, micrium

I have partitioned the NOR Flash into two regions, and trying to mount these two regions into separate volumes. But im getting the error

> `FS_FAT_VolOpen(): Invalid boot sec sig: 0xFFFF != 0xAA55.`

I have followed the steps

1. Opened the device

   FSDev_Open("nor:0:", (void *)&nor_cfg, &err);
2. Created the partition

```
FSDev_PartitionInit((CPU_CHAR*)"nor:0:",(FS_SEC_QTY )(6000),&err);
FSDev_PartitionAdd((CPU_CHAR*)"nor:0:",(FS_SEC_QTY )(6000),&err);
```

(Size of the flash is 8Mb)

verified the partition is created or not using

```
FSDev_GetNbrPartitions((CPU_CHAR*)"nor:0:",&err);
```

Its returning as 2.

3. Tried to format the regions using

```
FSVol_Open("vol:0:", "nor:0:", 1, &err);
FSVol_Open("vol:1:", "nor:0:", 2, &err);
```

error returned as "FS_ERR_PARTITION_NOT_FOUND":

I'm getting the error as

> `FSPartition_RdEntry(): Invalid partition sig: 0xFFFF != 0xAA55.`

Answer (score 0):

Try to format the regions with

```
FSVol_Open("vol:0:", "nor:0:", 0, &err);
FSVol_Open("vol:1:", "nor:0:", 1, &err);
```

I created two partitions 256MB and 768MB on the SD card. then formatted partitions with indices 1 and 2, and noticed that the partition with index 1 was created, but with a volume of 768MB, and the second one ended with an error. i changed the indices to 0 and 1 and it worked.
you need to create partitions only if they are not there, otherwise you will lose information on the media.